# How to limit the emails to pulled in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

Im using Outlook 2013. Is there a way to limit the emails to be pulled in outlook? Its taking too long in synchronizing

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what setup you have on your Outlook

**[IMAP](https://superuser.com/questions/298518/how-can-i-limit-the-number-of-imap-emails-outlook-2010-syncs)** account does not download email from the server into outlook.

**[IMAP](https://superuser.com/questions/298518/how-can-i-limit-the-number-of-imap-emails-outlook-2010-syncs)** account creates a mirror image of your folders in the server.

If you can setup **POP3** do the following.

1. Login to your account.
2. Create a new folder and move all the old emails (Except the recent email which you want) from Inbox the new folder created.
3. Remove the IMAP account created in outlook and setup the account as a POP3 account.
4. This will download only recent and the new emails that come in to the server.

> Note:

1. Setting the account as a POP3 account will only download the emails from the Inbox folder in the server. Other folders would not be synchronized.
2. POP3 account will permanently download all email from the server and there would not copy of the email like IMAP account. To avoid this, the option 'Leave a copy of email in the server' has to be enabled.